# Can python itertools.imap(func,p,q) work with a conditional test on the index (e.g. to get elements with odd indexes only)?

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I have the following arrays

```
>>> a
array([0, 8, 0, 8, 0, 8])
>>> b
array([0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6])
```

these represent the real and imaginary parts of a set of complex numbers.

I can reformat them into `numpy.complex` datatype using the following

```
>>> [x for x in itertools.imap(complex,a,b)]
[0j, (8+6j), 0j, (8+6j), 0j, (8+6j)]
```

However what I really want to get is only the elements with odd indexes:

```
[(8+6j),(8+6j),(8+6j)]
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[1::2]` takes every other item, starting on index 1 (the second), to the end of the list. That is:

```
>>> [x for x in itertools.imap(complex,a,b)][1::2]

[(8+6j), (8+6j), (8+6j)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0, 8, 0, 8, 0, 8])
>>> b = np.array([0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6])
>>> np.vectorize(complex)(a, b)[1::2]
array([ 8.+6.j,  8.+6.j,  8.+6.j])
```

That would be the best way but just for completeness, the `itertools` solution would be:

```
>>> from itertools import imap, islice
>>> list(islice(imap(complex,a,b), 1, None, 2))
[(8+6j), (8+6j), (8+6j)]
```